# Wifi Firmware for Wilocity Wil6210 802.11ad Wireless Network Adapter

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, wireless

I have an Acer Laptop running Ubuntu 16.04. The laptop has 802.11ad Wilocity wil6210 chip. The driver - wil6210 uses firmware **wil6210.fw** and **wil6210.brd**.

However, I could not find the firmware on the web.

The output of lspci is:

```
Network controller: Wilocity Ltd. Wil6200 802.11ad Wireless Network Adapter (rev 02)
```

The output of dmesg is:

```
[    1.182576] nouveau: detected PR support, will not use DSM
[    3.291185] wil6210 0000:03:00.0: wil6210 device found [1ae9:0310] (rev 2)
[    3.311999] wil6210 0000:03:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): wil_pcie_probe: CSR at [mem 0x84000000-0x841fffff 64bit] -> 0xffffb05983400000
[    3.328593] wil6210 0000:03:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): wil_set_capabilities: Board hardware is Sparrow B0
[    3.329535] wil6210 0000:03:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): _wil6210_disconnect: _wil6210_disconnect(bssid=          (null), reason=3, ev-)
[    3.394610] wil6210 0000:03:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): wil_get_bl_info: Boot Loader struct v2: MAC = 04:ce:14:07:85:b0 RF = 0x0000 (status 0x0000) bband = 0x00000000
[    3.394613] wil6210 0000:03:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): wil_get_bl_info: Boot Loader build 255.255.0.6836
[    3.394614] wil6210 0000:03:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): wil_set_oob_mode: wil_set_oob_mode: enable=0
[    3.492192] wil6210 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[    4.758824] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
[    5.072628] wil6210 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: _wil6210_disconnect: _wil6210_disconnect(bssid=          (null), reason=3, ev-)
[    5.138722] wil6210 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: wil_get_bl_info: Boot Loader struct v2: MAC = 04:ce:14:07:85:b0 RF = 0x0000 (status 0x0000) bband = 0x00000000
[    5.138723] wil6210 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: wil_get_bl_info: Boot Loader build 255.255.0.6836
[    5.138725] wil6210 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: wil_set_oob_mode: wil_set_oob_mode: enable=0
[    5.138727] wil6210 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: wil_reset: Use firmware <wil6210.fw> + board <wil6210.brd>
[    5.138893] wil6210 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for wil6210.fw failed with error -2
[    5.138895] wil6210 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: wil_request_firmware: ERR[ FW ]Failed to load firmware wil6210.fw
[  720.012611] wil6210 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: _wil6210_disconnect: _wil6210_disconnect(bssid=          (null), reason=3, ev-)
[  720.075072] wil6210 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: wil_get_bl_info: Boot Loader struct v2: MAC = 04:ce:14:07:85:b0 RF = 0x0000 (status 0x0000) bband = 0x00000000
[  720.075074] wil6210 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: wil_get_bl_info: Boot Loader build 255.255.0.6836
[  720.075076] wil6210 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: wil_set_oob_mode: wil_set_oob_mode: enable=0
[  720.075079] wil6210 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: wil_reset: Use firmware <wil6210.fw> + board <wil6210.brd>
[  720.075090] wil6210 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for wil6210.fw failed with error -2
[  720.075092] wil6210 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: wil_request_firmware: ERR[ FW ]Failed to load firmware wil6210.fw
```

Thank for any suggestions,
mg

Comment: Related: https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9739005/

Comment: I was able to get the firmware. However, I still have associating with 802.11ad router.

Comment: Your comment, "I still have associating..." is unclear. Please clarify.

Comment: I was not able to associate to AP. Sorry about that. I am able to associate now but without encryption. There seems to be some problem with wpa_supplicant. However, I can work without encryption. Thanks